# Is it correct to write: "I would appreciate it if you could inform me when you could contact my manager" in a formal email?

Tags: formality, politeness, email

I want to know if someone has eventually contacted my manager. I therefore want to send him a **formal** email to ask him **very politely**.

Is it correct to write as follow ?

"I would appreciate it if you could inform me anytime/when you could contact my manager."

Comment: You wrote 'has contacted' in the question which points to the event having already happened, but your question is about the future. Otherwise the version with 'when' is ok.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a writers workshop, nor a proofreading service; we can help you, however, if you identify a specific matter of grammar or usage that concerns you. In other words, why do you think the proposed phrasing is "correct" or "incorrect," and how have you tried to research the matter? Otherwise, the question will not be of use to anyone besides yourself, in addition to being subjective.

Comment: In fact, the person who I want to send email to has told me that he is going to send an email to my manager. However, I do not know if he has sent or not. So, I want to send him an email to be sure if he has sent the email. Thanks

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could inform me when you contact my manager or if you have already done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your examples really meet "normal usage".

Both of your examples are really asking for notification of WHEN it would be possible, not for when it has happened.

My choice would be something along the lines of:

`I would greatly appreciate it if you would let me know in the eventuality that you contact my current manager.`

Comment: As a reminder, answers on Stack Exchange should explain, not merely state. You don't directly answer the original question, which is itself substandard; you offer alternative wording, of which there might be a hundred equally valid variants, without providing any insight as to what makes it better than the original. -1

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I gave an answer that was useful to the OP, which was all I was trying to do in the first place. Way too many arguments on here about whether something matches the non-existant "rules of English grammar". This should probably have been on English Language Learners?

Comment: I hope OP doesn't actually use this when writing the their email.

Comment: No, I didn’t use it. I used myself phrase with “when”. I hope it was ok ...